# Register scheduled task from XML source

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have created a XML in which I have mentioned all the required parameters necessary for creating a Scheduled task. Now I have successfully imported the XMl through PowerShell script but I can't find the right way to call the XML as the parameter of the `Register-ScheduledTask` cmdlet.

Technet.microsoft states that the -Xml parameter "specifies XML string that contains Task definition".
Please provide me with the right syntax.

Comment: See https://www.petri.com/import-scheduled-tasks-powershell

Comment: Thanks you. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Define task in xml (task.xml) for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/daily-trigger-example--xml-

If you want to set "Run whether user is logged on or not" with different account then use below section in XML

```
<Principals>
    <Principal>
        <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
        <UserId>DOMAIN\UserName</UserId>
    </Principal>
</Principals>
```

Note: Password is not the actual password for username, but its LogonType 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal?view=win10-ps

2. Execute the below powershell command

   Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "app-task-name" -Xml (Get-Content "c:\apps\myapp\task.xml" | Out-String) -Force

   or

   Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "app-task-name" -Xml (Get-Content "c:\apps\myapp\task.xml" | Out-String) -Force -User "DOMAIN\UserName"  -Password "DOMAIN_Password"

   Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "app-task-name"

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/daily-trigger-example--xml-

Env:

- Windows 2012R2, Powershell 5.0